# Sending Email from centralized server with multiple web servers

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3, msmq, messaging

I am building a ASP.NET MVC3 application that will be running on a couple web servers. Instead of each server/app sending its own emails(Asnyc) per request, I would like to leverage something like MSMQ and send messages to an email server that would pick up the messages and send an email.

I have an idea of how to do this with a console app, windows service and MSMQ but was looking for some direction from anyone who has had success/experience implementing something similar. Any guidance, experience, technology, blog posts would be appreciated.

Comment: MSMQ doesn't have anything to do with email.
Do you want to send MSMQ messages to an Exchange server where a Windows service would read the incoming MSMQ messages and create emails from the message bodies?

Comment: @ John I was thinking I would build a EmailMessage object and send it as Binary data. I found this post that does what I was thinking http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Sending-email-from-ASP-NET-MVC-through-MVC-and-MSMQ-Part2.aspx but not sure if I like the solution.

Comment: You can send anything you like in an MSMQ message but you still need to write a service to read the message body and process it. You can't just send an EmailMessage object to Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see you're simply after an e-mail relay service. You could just use a dedicated IIS to do this for you. IIS SMTP has builtin queued mail relay functionallity. Preferably you want to cluster this IIS SMTP service for max. reliability.

Regarding the consideration in the article linked I can't see the difference between the users page process waiting for sending a message to an SMTP server and sending a message to a MSMQ.

I believe when it come to redundancy you'll find it much easier to set up a clustered SMTP service than clustered MSMQ.